# Table with values from sql database isn't appearing

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I wrote this code which is supposed to make a table with all vouchers and their values that user has redeemed but it won't work (nothing appears at all and no errors are being shown) so I'm confused what have I done wrong here. Can anybody help?

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=user_db;charset=utf8';

$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username1, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stm_voucher = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$stm_voucher->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm_voucher->execute();

while ($row = $stm_voucher->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row["id"];

    $stm_voucher2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE used_by = :id");
    $stm_voucher2->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm_voucher2->execute();

    $rank = 1;
    while ($row2 = $stm_voucher2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>{$rank}</td>
            <td>{$row2['voucher']}</td>
            <td>{$row2['value']}</td>
            <td>{$row2['used_on']}</td>
            </tr>";
        $rank++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can help. Because database samples and input values are missing.

Comment: @mario http://prntscr.com/nqm0f2 http://prntscr.com/nqm0v2

Comment: Is username really an int - `(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_INT)`?

Comment: `SELECT v.* FROM users AS u JOIN vouchers AS v ON u.id = v.used_by WHERE u.username = :username` - single query

Comment: When you have a question that involves databases, you should always provide the table definitions. The actual `CREATE` DML, not screenshots. Many times, people will recreate your tables and actually run the code before providing an answer. Do what you can to make it easy for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, use a Join instead of 2 queries as it will save a lot of performance and simplify your code.  In general the more you can do in the DB layer the less you have to code in the application.  Apx -6 lines of code in this case.

This should replace all the code you have in the question:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=user_db;charset=utf8';

$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username1, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT v.* FROM users AS u JOIN vouchers AS v ON u.id = v.used_by WHERE u.username = :username");
$stmt->execute([":username" => $username]);

$rank = 1;
while ($row2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>
        <td>{$rank}</td>
        <td>{$row2['voucher']}</td>
        <td>{$row2['value']}</td>
        <td>{$row2['used_on']}</td>
     </tr>";
     $rank++;
}
```

Don't forget the `<table></table>` tags.  I don't see them in this, or where is `$username` defined.  But I have to assume they are correct.

I came to the relationship between the 2 tables this way

IF `vouchers.used_by = :id` AND `->bindParam(":id", $id,..)` AND `$id = $row["users.id"];` then  `vouchers.used_by = users.id`.  Basically the equivalence principle.

JOIN's if you don't know, allow you to access multiple tables in a way that one (or more) field from the left table are related to a field in the right hand table (they are the same data).  The 2 most important ones are the `INNER JOIN` aka `JOIN` and the `LEFT JOIN` - a JOIN requires that there is a matching row in both tables, a LEFT JOIN requires only a matching row in the LEFT hand table.

So with a Left Join you can find rows that exist in only the left table, and a JOIN requires that there is a related row in both tables.  Based on you using only the id from the `users` table to pull the related record from the `vouchers` table it looks like you just need a regular `JOIN` as we can eliminate the need to look up the `users.id` because the JOIN does that. And, you only really need the data from the `vouchers` table.

Hope that makes sense.

In the comments `Nigel Ren` I think has the root of the problem:

> is username really an int - (":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_INT)

With PDO you can just put the input stuff in an array for execute. Which basically treats all the inputs as a string type.  So assuming `$username` is properly defined this should side step that issue too.  One would expect a username to be something like `myaccount` instead of `1`, a string instead of an int.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `Still doesn't work;` whats this mean, your going to have to provide more information than that.

Comment: Never mind, I had to retrieve username from the database and not id in this code, what a silly mistake.